# distance between all pixels of two images

Tags: python, opencv

I'm using python and opencv and a custom distance function `dist()` to calculate the distance between one main image and three test images.
The final image that is returned is `min(distance1, distance2, distance3)`
I'm currently going over both the axes of the images using a for loop and calculating the distance. This way it is very slow, as the for loops are slow. Is there any pythonic way to do this?

Each pixel of each image has two values (mu, sigma)

distance function that is used:

```
def w2distance2D(mu1, sig1, mu2, sig2):
    """

    Returns the Wasserstein distance between two 2-Dimensional normal distributions

    """
    t1 = np.linalg.norm(mu1 - mu2)

    #print t1
    t1 = t1 ** 2.0
    #print t1
    t2 = np.trace(sig2) + np.trace(sig1) 
    p1 = np.trace(np.dot(sig1, sig2))
    p2 =  (((np.linalg.det(np.dot(sig1, sig2)))))
    if p2 < 0.0:
        p2 = 0.0
    p2 = np.sqrt(p2)
    tt = p1 + 2.0*p2
    if tt < 0.0:
        tt = 0.0
    t3 = 2.0 * np.sqrt(tt)
    #print t3
    if (t1 + t2 - t3) < 0:
        result = 0.0
        #print "here"
    else:
        result = np.sqrt(t1 + t2 - t3)

    return result
```

Comment: Without knowing the specifics of your `dist()` function, it's very hard to say anything specifically useful. I would therefore recommend parallelization: look to `multiprocessing` or `concurrent.futures`

Comment: I have added the distance function

Comment: Python is a language for doing tricky things (like web-servers), fast programming or using c-modules. You shouldn't make heavy calculations on it. My suggestion is to rewrite it on C (hard way) or cython (easy way) — this will make your calculation much faster.